# Empty space at the end of a page in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

In Chrome, my site has a bunch of empty space at the end.

Some pages have lots of empty space, some have none. I'm not sure what the problem is, I've tried lots of different changes in the css (using chrome's inspect element), but nothing fixes the problem.

There is no problem in Firefox, I don't know about IE right now.

Edit: Removed links. None of those pages exist any more.

Comment: For the record, I'm using Chromium in Linux, and there's no empty space.

Comment: I see nothing wrong on Google Chrome 12.0.742.30 dev. Mind posting a screenshot?

Comment: @Blender - http://cl.ly/2p0V2b0j1G1h0415442F (though I'm going to put the fix from alex soon). It appears that it's a bug only in the current stable release, same to @Jeffrey, Chromium gets updates before chrome, so it seems it's only chrome stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the last `hr` element.

It has `display: inline-block`.

Remove that property value and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It has been listed as a rendering bug: see here

http://41.206.47.2/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6d78452432a4c4d7&hl=en

Seems to have been fixed in later dev versions. I get the same issue in 11.0.696.65

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Hopefully they push the update for that bug soon.